# How to combine Characters and Non Character values in a SQL Union (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to print a row in my SQL result, which represent column captions. The columns captions are only VARCHAR values. Now I have the problem, that a get the following error message: "ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression":

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT 'MyFirstString', 
           'MySecondString',
           'MyThirdString'
     FROM DUAL
                           )

UNION 

(
    SELECT firstCol,   // contains number
           secondCol,  // contains DATE
           thirdCol    // contains VARCHAR2
                                               )
```

How can I solve this problem. Additional column captions are necessary, since i must be export my data in another files (such as CSV, PDF...)

Comment: CAST non-character data to character type.

Comment: You should also use `union all` instead of `union` to avoid the overhead of removing the duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use to_char cast

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT 'MyFirstString', 
           'MySecondString',
           'MyThirdString'
     FROM DUAL
                           )

UNION 

(
    SELECT to_char(firstCol),   // contains number
           to_char(secondCol),  // contains DATE
           thirdCol    // contains VARCHAR2(no need cast here since its already string)
                                           )
```

You will later maybe need to cast it back to what it was depends on what you will want to do with it.

For date you can use to_date , number to_decimal\to_number and ETC..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, and export the table with headers.

```
SELECT firstCol as 'MyFirstString',   // contains number
       secondCol as 'MySecondString',  // contains DATE
       thirdCol as 'MyThirdString'   // contains VARCHAR2
```

Comment: No, I need the column caption in a separated row !!

Comment: @Marwief note the "export the table with headers", that should add another row to the CSV result.

Comment: `as 'MyFirstString'` is invalid SQL. Single quotes are for string constants, not for identifiers.